# Accessing parts of a JSON response using Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have some JSON response data that are multiple levels deep. However, I only need to retrieve part of it at any one time in a step-by-step wizard style page. In the first step of the wizard, a top-level object `category_a` (which contains an array of objects) is needed, in the next step, another top-level object `category_b` is used and so on.

At each step, backbone will create several `ProductView` views and append to a div `#photo_list`. Each `ProductView` view will use the `img` object of an element in the array.

**Problem:** How should I access the top-level objects one at a time, given my template file (which can be edited/improved) shown below which I try to make it as simple as possible.

**Example JSON response**

*Object names like `category_a` and the number of objects can vary*

```
{"category_a":[
    {"product_id":6283,
    "img":"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/img\/6283_5e093.jpg"},

    {"product_id":6284,
    "img":"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/img\/6284_5e093.jpg"}
    ],

"category_b":[
    {"product_id":6283,
    "img":"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/img\/6283_5e093.jpg"},

    {"product_id":6284,
    "img":"http:\/\/www.mysite.com\/img\/6284_5e093.jpg"}
    ]
}
```

**Backbone.js Code**

*`productList` currently contains the entire JSON response*

```
ProductCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/api/someurl',
    model: Product
});

ProductListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#photo_list',

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(product, index){
            $(this.el).append(new ProductView({ model: product }).render().el);
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});

ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagname: 'div',
    className: 'photo_box',

    template: _.template($('#tpl-PhotoListItemView').html()),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
        return this;
    }
});
```

**Creating the Collection+Views**

```
this.productList = new ProductCollection();
var self = this;
self.productListView = new ProductListView({ collection: self.productList });
this.productList.fetch();
```

**Template Snippet**

```
<div class="photo_container">
    <img src="<%= img %>" class='photo' />
</div>
```

Comment: Have you already looked at http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse or http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think if I were to use the collection's `parse` function, I will need to do a `fetch` every time I want to access another  top-level object. I decided to fetch all the data that I need in one request so I would not need to make additional calls back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar (appending items from a JSON response), but I'm doing it all in one view, which may or may not work for your needs. Thought I would share just in case it's helpful.

My template looks like this:

```
<div id="folders" data-role="content">
    <div class="content-primary">
        <ul data-role="listview" id="foldersListView" data-filter="true">
        <!-- insert folders here -->
        <% for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) { %>
            <% var folder = folders[i]; %>
            <li id=<%= folder.displayName %>><h3><%= folder.displayName %></h3><span class="ui-li-count"><%= folder.count %></span><ul></ul></li>
        <% } %>
        <!-- done inserting -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the initialize function of my view, I simply have to pass the JSON object and the template will step through each item for me.

```
initialize : function() {
    _.bindAll(this, "render", "logoutAction");
    this.template = _.template($("#folders").html(), { folders : app.folders.toJSON() });
    // Add the template HTML to the body.
    $(this.el).html(this.template);
},
```

And after sharing all that, I think the easier solution for you may be to just step through each item when creating the views.

```
this.productList = new ProductCollection();
var self = this;
productListJSON = self.productList.toJSON()
$.each(productListJSON, function(product) {
    new ProductListView({ product: productListJSON[product].product });
});
```